# Metallib in iOS 13

Tags: metal, ios13

I've upgraded to iOS 13 and now my metallib is not loading.

> Domain=MTLLibraryErrorDomain Code=1 "This library format is not supported on this platform (or was built with an old version of the tools)"

I've tried re-building it without luck. Do I need Catalina for this?

Comment: Are you using the Beta Xcode to build your app?  What is the deployment target of your app?

Comment: deployment target is iOS 11, and I was the beta, I got it to work with non beta and iPhone target.

Comment: It seems that you are trying to load shader library (`MTLLibrary`) that was built using older Xcode. Are you sure that you sure that you've rebuilt everything including shaders?

Comment: I was getting this exact error, perhaps for a different reason. The issue was that I had `-fcikernel` option under **Other Metal Linker Flags** and **Other Metal Compiler Flags** in the target's **Build Settings**. Removing them made the exception go away.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue when I compile the metal shaders for macosx, like it described in documentation of the Apple.

```
xcrun -sdk macosx metal -c MyLibrary.metal -o MyLibrary.air
xcrun -sdk macosx metallib MyLibrary.air -o MyLibrary.metallib
```

But for iOS, we should compile it for ios sdk like:

```
xcrun -sdk iphoneos metal -c MyLibrary.metal -o MyLibrary.air
xcrun -sdk iphoneos metallib MyLibrary.air -o MyLibrary.metallib
```